# Delete a specific category when deleting a user

Tags: categories, user-registration, customization

I'm using the following function to create a portfolio category named "tips_username" when a user registers on my website.

```
add_action('user_register', 'auto_create_traveltip_category');
function auto_create_traveltip_category($user_id) {
    $tip_category_name = 'tips_' . $_POST['user_login'];
    wp_insert_term($tip_category_name, 'portfolio_entries', array(
            'description' => 'Travel Tip for ' . $_POST['user_login'],
            'slug'        => 'tips-' . $_POST['user_login'],
            'parent'      =>  '',
            )
    );
}
```

This is working fine, but now I need a function to automatically delete the category when I delete a user, for example from the user list.
I implemented the following function taking inspiration from https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/delete_user:

```
function delete_traveltip_category_with_user($user_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $user_obj = get_userdata($user_id);
    $tip_cat_name = 'tips_' . $user_obj->user_login;
    $tip_cat_desc = get_term_by('name', $tip_cat_name, 'portfolio_entries');
    $tip_cat_id = $tip_cat_desc->term_id;
    wp_delete_term( $tip_cat_id, 'portfolio_entries' );
}
add_action( 'delete_user', 'delete_traveltip_category_with_user' );
```

Unfortunately it is not working. Can you please have a look and tell me what's wrong with it? Thanks!!

Comment: When you say it's not working, what exactly happens?

Comment: When I delete a user (i.e. testuser), the corresponding portfolio category "tips_testuser" is not deleted.

Comment: Ok. What debugging steps have you taken so far?

Comment: Just echo the vars but without success. Is there a better way to debug?

Comment: So what values did you have for $user_id, $user_obj and the rest?

Comment: If you read the documentation for get_term_by you'll see that there's a warning that you must coerce the ID to an integer. If you don't then your deletion will fail. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by#Return_Values

Comment: Ok. The issue is in `get_user_data($user_id)`. In fact when I do `echo $tip_cat_name` I only get the existing string "tips_". I think that `get_user_data($user_id)` is getting the current user, while I need the data of the user which is going to be deleted instead.

Comment: So if you print_r $user_obj what do you get?

Answer (score 1):

1. [`delete_user`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_user/#source-code) action involves two parameters: `$id` and `$reassign`. So you should specify two parameters for the hook.
2. Because [`sanitize_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_term/) and [`sanitize_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_user/) use different ways to sanitize strings, `'tips_' . $_POST['user_login']` and `'tips_' . $user_obj->user_login` are not always the same string. So it's better to use `'tips_' . sanitize_user($_POST['user_login')` as term name when inserting the term.